# Get Sharepoint list in XML

Tags: sharepoint-server, xml

I found a way to export my sharepoint list in XML but it's not working on my new tenant
So if I try to do it on my new tenant, I get all meta data between

```
<s:Schema></s:Schema>
```

but I have nothing in my

```
</rs:data>
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the SharePoint list in XML?

Comment: Add your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get list's xml by calling following URL:

```
https://your_site/your_subsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={GUID}&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

The {GUID} in the URL above must be replaced by GUID of your list.

Another way, we can access SharePoint List in Ms-Access, and then export tables to XML in Access.

Reference:

[EXPORT SHAREPOINT LIST DATA TO XML DIRECTLY FROM THE GUI](https://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/export-sharepoint-list-data-to-xml-directly-from-the-gui/)